# automatically log out in phpBB3 ( integrated into Joomla via jFusion )

Tags: joomla, authentication, phpbb3

I have a website based on Joomla 2.5. There is a forum (phpBB3) integrated into it by jFusion. I set in the jFusion configurations to use dual-login. Now I can log in from both Joomla and phpBB but I have a problem: after I have logged in, I can browser through the phpBB forum posts but when I want to create a new topic or reply to post, I am asked to log in again and after I re-input my account and password I am brought to the default page. Actually what happens is that when I submit my reply, I am automatically logged out so that I am brought to the page for inputting account name and password instead of the page saying something like "reply is successful". I then input my account/password again and the same circle again. Always blocked out for creating a post or replying.

I thought it was a cookie issue but I have double-checked. My cookie settings in jFusion and phpBB ACP are the same. And I am logged out automatically in every new page, but only in some pages ( seemingly those pages posting new content to the forum ). Here are my cookie settings:

- cookie domain: example.com
- cookie path: /
- cookie prefix: phpbb3_yyy

(I masked my strings by "example" and "yyy")

Might it possibly be a problem about user rights? The phpBB is migrated from another site and I didn't change thing so there shouldn't be any issue about rights I imagine.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your cookie domain to `.example.com` with a leading dot.